# Understanding PHP Sessions in Magento

Tags: php, session, magento

Im having trouble figuring out a couple things regarding sessions, the browser, and Magento (or probably any shopping cart for that matter). I understand that by default 24 minutes of inactivity will close a session. I am also under the the understanding that when you completely exit a browser, that session is also closed.

To test the second part I accessed my Magento store, added a product into my cart, and completely exited my browser. I reopened my browser and the product was still in the cart. How is that so? Does the PHP garbage collector only run at certain times? I figured that session would be dead therefore couldnt link up to the cookie that is stored on my machine. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native PHP sessions use a cookie with a 0 expiry, which will be cleared immediately upon browser window being closed.  Magento's session cookie (as Emi noted) has a 3 hour expiry and will persist between browser sessions, so closing/opening the browser window won't cause the session to be restarted.  The Firefox web developer toolbar, or Chrome's developer tools will allow you to forcibly clear the cookie and restart the session if that's what you want to do.

I should also note that although the cookie name is different and it has an expiry time, under the hood Magento does use PHP's native session support.  This means that settings in the php.ini relating to max session lifetime, etc will also affect Magento's sessions.

Also, since Magneto 1.6 (and EE 1.11) there's a feature called [persistent shopping cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/) which establishes a long term cookie for the purpose of maintaining your shopping cart between sessions.  If your test to see whether your session is maintained is just looking at the cart this feature may be making it look like your session is much longer than it actually is..

Answer (score 1):

The server can't really tell the difference between closing a window, just staying on the page, or browsing around. At least, not without extra scripting, which isn't built into Magento. If you want to test a session, either wait the 24 minutes, try another browser, or clear all the session files on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are stored local on the site's server (in most cases in file system, but you can use other type of data storage like: database, apc, memcached...) this is configured in local.xml.
When stored in file system you can find them under /path_to_site_root/var/sessions
I believe you have 3 models that use sessions: 'core/session', 'customer/session' and 'admin/session'
Also you can configure php's garbage collector: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

When you close your browser, if cookie has expire set to 0 it won't be used anymore http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
Magento's default cookie is called frontend and I think it has expire set to at least and hour, also you can't modify this cookie from javascript, since it's http only.